# html dropdown - 1st item in dropdown is not able to select

Tags: asp.net, jquery-mobile

I have a html dropdown in my jquery mobile application which is populating from database. But the 1st item is selectable but unable to display in select control.How to do this?

My code is

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain" style="width: 50%">
    <label for="selectmenu22">
        <span style="font-family: times new roman,times; 
font-size: medium;">
            <b>Address Type:</b>
        </span>
     </label>
     <select name="ddlAddressType" id="ddlAddresstype" 
         data-theme="b" data-mini="true" runat="server" required="required">
     </select>
</div>
```

Comment: updated code using jquery mobile controls

Comment: Where are the items within the select?  What do you mean by "the 1st item is selectable but unable to display in select control"?  What is the problem?

Comment: i m fetching from database using json.If there is only one item for a particular ID it doesnot display in dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery Mobile and asp.net web forms don't play nicely together. Ajax loading and the PostBack model just don't mesh. You haven't provided your JavaScript which is suspect but consider turning off Ajax loading.

```
<form runat="server" data-ajax="false">
   ...
</form>
```

Comment: Well you will need to provide more information with your question. Show us some code.